# Exporting some tables from Azure SQL to Cosmos DB for PowerBI visualization

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, databricks

I have a situation where most of my organization's data sits at Azure SQL. Now we are including one more data source which gives 1GB of structured data daily. My objective is that I have to merge this 1GB with the Azure SQL data and give it to the PowerBI. I can't do this on PowerBi because it is slow.

1. Now should I choose CosmosDB as a sink and replicate some of the Azure SQL tables to CosmosDB?so that I will have stored procedure at cosmos which does the required merge and places it in the final tables at cosmos for PowerBi to pick up.
2. Or should I choose some other sink? (I can have appendblob but it has a 200GB upper limit. I can have Azure table storage but then how can I merge with Azure SQL data?

Any recommendations on what to do?

Comment: putting 1GB/day into SQL Server/SQL Azure does not seem problematic, so I'm not sure why you are bothering with other solutions in this case.  PowerBI works great on top of SQL Server and you can generally use columnstores to get decent performance for tabular pass-through queries from Power BI.

Comment: But as far as I know there is some limit to the amount of GBs to store in Azure SQL DB?

Comment: Until recently, the limit for a single DB was 4TB (which you aren't near).  That is _after_ compression, so columnstores can be used to store a ton of data in that single database.  In any event, SQL Azure Hyperscale was just announced and you can have giant databases with this technology:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale-faq

Comment: Thanks Conor. However, I am pretty sure that it gonna cost a lot as compared to the prices of the Azure SQL DB now.

Comment: The pricing for hyperscale allows you to scale storage somewhat separately than compute.  That should generally keep your prices lower at larger data scales.  In any event, your problem still seems cheaper to keep on a single sql azure db (without hyperscale) instead of paying for two different systems and replicating data all over the place.

Comment: Thanks Conor. Appreciated.